# AngularJS page keeps reloading

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js

I made an API using Node. I tested my API using Postman and that is working fine. So I started with Angular to display the page.

So when I visit the page `http://localhost:3000/tests` the page keeps reloading all the time! I don't understand why since I just request some JSON from the server and show that on the page...

Below the code:

modules/core.js:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'test']);
})();
```

controllers/test.js:

```
(function() {

    angular.module('test', [])
        .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/tests', {
                    templateUrl: '/views/tests.html',
                    controller: 'TestController',
                })

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }])
        .controller('TestController', ['$http', '$scope', '$routeParams', function ($http, $scope, $routeParams) {
            $http.get('/api/tests')
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.tests = data;
                });
        }]);

})();
```

views/tests.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="test" ng-repeat="test in tests">
            <h4>{{ test.title }}</h4>
            <p><small>{{ test.url }}</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

views/index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title>MEAN App</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <script src="/controllers/test.js"></script>
        <script src="/modules/core.js"></script>
        <style>
            body { padding-top:80px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-view>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browsers are experiencing this behavior?

Comment: I'm using FireFox, but I tested Chrome as well and they have the same behavior!

Comment: Same issue here and haven't been able to resolve. Although try investigating the log from your "npm start" command window. In my case it was requesting for my home.html and favicon.ico and was getting a 404 repeatedly. I am not sure why that would keep reloading the page though. Probably a case of invalid template URL somewhere